# Zoom on browser without triggering responsive styling css

Tags: css, browser

So I have this footer

[image]

And I want to work on pixel stuff like the precise weight of the police or thing like this which can only be seen by view if I zoom on it.

My problem is that when I zoom on it, using the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>. I got this.

[image]

**Due to my CSS since it is a responsive footer.**

So **I'd like to be able to zoom on an element without triggering my responsive styling.** Example `@media(max-width:768px){ #writing { display:none } }`  or any of the properties that could be affected to the resize of my window.

I could undo the style apply at `max-width:...` by commenting or unchecked it in the dev' tool but this is not what I'm looking for.

Is there an other way to do it ? Maybe a browser extension or a kind of 'zoom in your screen' commande?

### EDIT

I found my answer look below :)

Comment: What have you tried? [How to ask a **good** question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have I tried? I've zoomed in my browser with a classical cmd+. I'll edit my post since it seems not clear.

Comment: try setting your widths in em for the footer maybe? but this is just a quick guess

Comment: I dont get what could it change ? @vlrprbttst Anyway this is a full-width footer (100%)

Comment: ems are a percentage unit, when the browser window upscales and you have pixel widths, i think it just doesnt zoom as you would expect to. with ems, it might scale proportionally. give it a try, im just guessing. never cared about browser force zooming so i don't really know

Comment: you can't see the text in your footer because it's contained in a fixed width "cell", the text gets larger and it goes on a second line, which you can't see

Comment: @vlrprbttst Well I tried just for test it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the simplest way of doing that is by zooming on your screen.

### Solution for Mac User

- <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> -> **Zooming In**
- <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> -> **Zooming Out**

If you know the way of doing it on Pc I'll add it to the answer.
Hope this could help !